# Positioning Absolute Relative to Dynamic Height

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Wanting to position an overlay on top of images that may have different heights. The position that I am hoping to is similar to this:

[image: An image describing the intended layout]

The parent container in this image has these properties:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
width: calc(100% + 60px);
margin: 0px -30px;
```

The child container has these properties:

```
width: calc(100% + 13px);
height: calc(100% + 130px);
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin-left: -13px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
pointer-events: none;
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/testname44/pen/xxywdYx)'s a codepen with a rough markup along with the current styles. How might I position this child absolutely within its parent container based on that container's height?

Answer (score 0):

I put the parent and child elements in to the `container div` additionally gave `flex attribute` and writed some code like below. I hope it works for you.

```css
.container{
    height:100vh;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
} 


.box {
    display: block;
    width:40vw;
    height:70vh;
    background-color: rgb(78, 77, 77);
    position:relative;
}


.box2 {
    display:block;
    width:12vw;
    height:25vh;
    background-color: rgb(155, 152, 152);
    bottom:1em;
    left:1em;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box2">
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```